# Keeping Layout Same in any Window Size

Tags: css, layout, window

Im making a website in html using css as a layout. However, noticed that the page looks really different in full window than it does it does half of the window. I've tried using position, overflow, float and all of that, but it dosen't seem to help?

heres my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="type/html;
charset=ANSI"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Hidden\Desktop\Website Main\Webpages\Main Style Sheet.css"
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="column-center">

<img id="flag" src=" C:\Users\Hidden\Desktop\Website Main\Images\Flag.jpg" align="left"> <hr/>

    <hr/>
 </div>
   <div class="column-left"> </div>
   <div class="column-right"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and heres the css:

```
HTML {height: 98%;}
body {
background-color: #614051;
 padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%
}
.container{
background-color: #fdf3e7;
border: 2px solid silver;
margin: 5px;
width: 98%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
.column-left{ 
float: left; 
width: 24%;
background-color: #edc9af;
height: 100%;
}
.column-right{ 
float: right; 
width: 24%;
background-color: #edc9af;
height: 100%; 
}
.column-center{ 

display: inline-block; 
width: 575px; 
overflow: visible;
height: 100%
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}
#flag {
margin: 5px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
}
```

how do i make it appear the same in the large window panel and the small window panel?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking how to make your site responsive? There's many ways to achieve that.. look into css media queries, there are also frameworks you can work with (i.e foundation, bootstrap) ..

Comment: btw, in your simple example, you have a few elements with fixed width (#flag, .column-center, etc), if you change them all to work with %, you might get a more a less fluid layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change your `.column-center` width to: 50%.

You can't have left and right column with responsive size and the main with fixed and work properly to all screen sizes.